# NSMutableArray null in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the following code to determine the distance between my logged in user and all other users in the database. I'm successfully able to add the found distances to NSMutableArray finalDistances, however I'm now trying to display those distances in my tableview cells in label kmAway. I want to display them in the same order they're returned in each cell.

That said, when I try to implement that as shown in ViewController.m, self.finalDistances is returned as null in my tableview, even though it's populated inside the viewDidLoad. How can I accomplish this?

**ViewController.h**

```c
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationDistance kilometers;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocation *startLocation;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocation *endLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *finalDistances;
```

**ViewController.m**

```c
NSString *myLocation = self.currentUser[0][@"street_address"];
NSLog(@"MY LOCATION %@", myLocation);

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks2, NSError* error) {
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks2)
    {        
        for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocationsFriend in self.closeByNeighbours) {

            NSString *location = [multiplelocationsFriend objectForKey:@"address"];

            CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
            [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
                if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                    CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                self.endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:placemark.location.coordinate.longitude];

                NSString *myLocation = self.currentUser[0][@"street_address"];
                NSLog(@"MY LOCATION %@", myLocation);

                CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks2, NSError* error) {
                    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks2)
                    {
                        self.startLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude] ;
                        self.kilometers = [self.startLocation distanceFromLocation:self.endLocation] / 1000;
                        self.finalDistances = [NSMutableArray new];
                        [self.finalDistances addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.kilometers]];
                        [self.neighboursView reloadData];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}
}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.neighboursView reloadData];
});

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"sidebarCell";

    self.sidetableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    if (tableView == self.neighboursView)
    {   
        sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];

        NSDictionary *userName = [self.closeByNeighbours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *first = [userName objectForKey:@"first name"];
        NSString *last = [userName objectForKey:@"last name"];
        NSString *area = [userName objectForKey:@"neighbourhood"];
        NSString *city = [userName objectForKey:@"city"];

        NSDictionary *distances = [self.finalDistances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [[cell kmAway] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", distances]];

        [[cell areaLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", area, city]];

        NSDictionary *userBio = [self.closeByNeighbours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [[cell username] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last]];


        NSString *profilePath = [[self.closeByNeighbours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];

        [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];


        return cell;            
    } 

    ...
```

Comment: I took a shot at answering this, but it's a big code block that is not easy to analyze without the rest of the context it's running in. The more you can isolate and clarify your question, the more likely you are to get a useful response (and answer the question yourself).

Comment: I formatted the code so that code blocks were not unnecessarily intended and things line up. However, there are a bunch of bits that don't make sense. The first second of code (after the properties) isn't in a function. Then later down, there is a dispatch_async followed by a failure block that isn't attached to anything.

Answer (score 1):

`self.finalDistances` isn't set until the completion handler on `CLGeocoder` is run. Additionally, it is reset to an empty `NSMutableArray` each pass through the `for` loop in the completion handler.

However, there may be other bugs as well.

Comment: Tried to par it down a bit lol! That said... I removed the NSMutableArray reset line (didnt catch that, thank you). self.finalDistances is still null - that said, is it because of this line by chance? NSDictionary *distances = [self.finalDistances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; I wasn't sure if objectAtIndex was the correct move :/  Or, I thought perhaps I needed to make the NSMutableArray mutableCopy? As for it not being set until the handler is done, I thought running tableview reload at the end would rectify that...

Comment: It's really hard to read the code. It's very poorly formatted. I'll take a shot at formatting it so you can learn how to improve it for future posts.

Comment: I agree with @DougRichardson , if you put" self.finalDistances = [NSMutableArray new];" inside the for loop, the array will be "cleaned" every loop.